# Can I rewrite the URL fed to Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I would like to use a suffix at the end of the URL in a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) app to determine what format the response takes.

So `http://foo/bar.json` would result in a json response, `http://foo/bar.xml` in a xml one, and `http://foo/bar` in a plain HTML page.

I was trying to do that in an initial bloc - in a `begin` or `auto` action - by rewriting the URL that's fed to dispatching for subsequent actions, but that does not seem to work.

And suggestions about this? Including objections - it might not be such a good idea after all.

Thanks -

Comment: How about making the urls of the form `http://foo.com/bar/json`, `http://foo.com/bar/xml`, etc., and then using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408408/what-is-the-best-way-to-hanlde-optional-url-arguments-in-a-catalyst-controller

Answer (score 1):

```
sub type : Regex('foo/bar(\.[^/]+)?') {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    my ( $type) = @{ $c->req->captures };
    $c->log->info("Type: ".$type);
    $c->response->body( $c->welcome_message );
}
```

You can try the above code, now based on the $type you will have to switch your view to json/xml/html.