# Catalyst: match URL with specific but optional arguments

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm trying to write a Catalyst Controller that matches a specific path but with a single optional argument. This seems like something that would be perfect for `Regex`, but this is deprecated, and I can't figure out how to use Chained to accomplish this. Also, I don't really want to have multiple methods, which is how Chained seems to work--I just want one.

(I see that there's been a previous discussion of this at [what is the best way to hanlde optional url arguments in a Catalyst controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408408/what-is-the-best-way-to-hanlde-optional-url-arguments-in-a-catalyst-controller), but this is from nine years ago, and it's still not clear to me.)

All I'm trying to do is match a path which can have exactly four or five arguments. I'm using Catalyst::Controller::REST, if that affects things.

```
sub review : Path('/review') : Args(4) : ActionClass('REST') {}
sub review_GET {
    my ( $self, $c, $catalog_id, $item_id, $order_no, $event_id, $OPTIONAL_SOMETHING_ELSE) = @_;
    # do stuff...
}
```

That's basically it. If I have a plain `Args()`, then I can match any number of arguments, but I don't want this: I want to match *only* four or five arguments. (I don't need to worry about type constraints; I handle that in code.) But the processing of this should be the same; I don't want to have a totally different method to handle the four-argument vs. the five-argument call, which seems to be how `Chained` would work. The same would go for having two methods, one with `Args(4)` and one with `Args(5)`--they shouldn't be separated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the URL look like you are trying to match?

Comment: It looks like `http://example.com/review/873/2942/19823/3`, possibly with an extra `/9394` at the end. But nothing else, i.e. if it's `/review` with anything other than four or five arguments, it should not match.

Comment: @simbabque does that help?

Comment: I think you need to run with two endpoints or one that slurps. I can't find anything in the docs either, and I use Catalyst all the time at work. Sorry.

Comment: OK, thanks for looking this over.